# Hibernate Query version of Compound select

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have the following java classes:

```
class Person {
   private long id;
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private Company company;
   ...
}

class Company{
   private long id;
   private String name;
   private String Country;
   private long sector_id;
   ...
}

class ProjectParticipants {
   private long id;
   private long project_id;
   private long person_id;
}
```

If I want to select all persons from a particular company I can do:

```
List<Person>=session.createQuery("from Person where company_id:companyId").setLong("companyId",companyId).list();
```

If I wanted to find the project participants, for a specific project from a specific company, in SQL I could do:
    select * from Person p, ProjectParticipants r where p.id=r.person_id and r.project_id= and p.company_id=;

or

```
select * from Person where id in (select person_id from ProjectParticipants where project_id=<project_id>) and company_id=<company_id>;
```

However, it seems that to use a hibernate query object this cannot work unless I instance the company. Is there a way to make this query without having to instance a company object from its id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "instance the company"? For this object structure and (absence of) mapping you can do it parallel to your SQL:

`select p from Person p where p.companyId=:companyId and p.id in (select pp.personId from ProjectParticipant pp where pp.projectId=:projectId)`

i.e.

```
Query q = em.createQuery("select p from Person p where p.companyId=:companyId and p.id in (select pp.personId from ProjectParticipant pp where pp.projectId=:projectId)");
q.setParameter("companyId", 2L);
q.setParameter("projectId", 1L);
List resultList = q.getResultList();
```

But this is not how you would model the many-to-many relation in Java at all, and of course the query would look different for mapped relationships. Hibernate is a mapper for useful business object structures to relational databases. That is why your first SQL variant (with the manual join) will not translate 1:1 into HQL/JPQL but look different.

Comment: Yes thanks, I am not that expert in HQL and I just figured you can express an object's id as in the example